# How to retrieve data from xml file in Portlet

Tags: java, xml, liferay, portlet

I am using liferay technology and  trying to retrieve data from xml file in portlet dynamically by using SAXBuilder but it is not working. If you have any idea then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) library

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);

SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
org.dom4j.Document doc = reader.read(is);
is.close();
Element content = doc.getRootElement();  //this will return the root element in your xml file
List<Element> methodEls = content.elements("element"); // this will retun List of all Elements with name "element"
```

Comment: I got value of node but in attribute value i Stored that attribute value in NamedNodeMap but not able to iterate  over the map

Comment: So what's your question about dom4j?